# .NET Regex Negative Lookahead - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

Assuming I have:

```
StartTest
  NoInclude
EndTest

StartTest
  Include
EndTest
```

and am using:

```
/StartTest(?!NoInclude)[\s\S]*?EndTest/g
```

Why am I matching both groups?

Regexr example: http://regexr.com/3db8m

Answer (score 3):

You fail the match with the lookahead if `NoInclude` appears straight after `StartTest`. You need a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
(?s)StartTest(?:(?!(?:Start|End)Test|NoInclude).)*EndTest
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fs)StartTest(%3f%3a(%3f!(%3f%3aStart%7cEnd)Test%7cNoInclude).)*EndTest&i=StartTest%0d%0a++NoInclude%0d%0aEndTest%0d%0a%0d%0aStartTest%0d%0a++Include%0d%0aEndTest)

The regex is matching `StartTest`, then matches any text that is not `StartTest`, `EndTest` or `NoInclude`, up to the `EndTest`.

Since the `*` is greedy, it will make the `.` match as much as it can. The negative lookahead will make it stop matching at the locations that are followed with the following alternatives:

- `(?:Start|End)Test` - `StartTest` or `EndTest`
- `NoInclude` - just `NoInclude`.

**NOTE**: The `(?s)` is an inline modifier (equivalent of `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag) that modifies the `.` behavior in a pattern making it match LF (newlines), too. Without this modifier (or without `RegexOptions.Singleline`) a dot matches any character but a newline.

**NOTE2**: If you are testing a regex outside of the native code environment, make sure you are using an appropriate tester for your regex flavor. regexr.com only supports JavaScript flavor, regex101.com supports JS, PCRE and Python flavors, and RegexStorm.net/RegexHero.net support .NET flavor. There are many more testers around, read what they support and what not first.

Here is a [C# demo](http://ideone.com/hkprwJ):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var input = "StartTest\n  NoInclude\nEndTest\n\nStartTest\n  Include\nEndTest";
        var regex = new Regex(@"(?s)StartTest(?:(?!(?:Start|End)Test|NoInclude).)*EndTest");
        var results = regex.Matches(input).Cast<Match>()
                       .Select(p => p.Value)
                       .ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", results));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Wiktor.  I can't tell you how much of a headache regex gives me.  I've spent hours going over a hundred tutorials and I just can not wrap my head around it.  The syntax is so freaking terse that I feel like I'd have to use it daily for weeks to really get comfortable with it, lol!

Comment: Well, actually, you can do the whole thing without a regex, or with a simpler `(?s)StartTest.*?EndText` regex and then get only those matches that do not contain `NoInclude`. Tempered greedy token is a bit costly, although .NET regex engine is really efficient.

Comment: Ok, I saw you edited this a couple of times - we went from simple to something I don't understand, again, lol.  What is "(?:(?!(?:"  Start OR End is simple enough, but I'm lost from there... I was going to add more to the OP, but it seems I can't.  Let me read through that link you provided, see if I can get somewhere with this.   I really freaking hate regex.

Comment: Wiktor, any chance you'd have a similar in-depth tutorial like that link, but for .NET's version of Regex?  I think that's the dilemma I'm having - I keep finding tutorials for a bunch of 'flavors' of Regex, and none of them seem to say "HEY I'M FOR JAVA" or "HEY PCRE HERE"

Comment: Updated with round 2 question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36969519/net-regex-negative-lookahead-what-am-i-doing-wrong-round-2

Comment: I'm on a walk with my daughter. I will post C#code when I'm back.

Comment: What round two? You did not use my regex in full by leaving out (?s)?

Comment: Wiktor, (?s) is giving me Invalid target for quantifier on regexr.com

Comment: Well, that would be a problem, then... *sigh*  Thanks for pointing that out, rock321987.  I've grown fond of the Explain tab on regexr.com!

Comment: @John: I am sorry to leave the question unattended, but it is my wife to blame (and my two kids). However, I provided you with the correct regex and correct demo link. If you wrote "I test it at regexr.com, and it does not work", I would explain everything at once, right from the sandpit. You wrote you need a tutorial. Please always be precise.

Comment: Wiktor, it's not a problem - I'm lucky that my wife and son are letting me try to get some work done this weekend, so I know family comes first.  Thank you for your help, either way!