# .NET Regex Negative Lookahead - What am I doing wrong (round 2!)

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I asked this previously and used what I believe to be entirely too simple of a construct, so I'm trying again...

Assuming that I have:

```
This is a random bit of information from 0 to 1.
  This is a non-random bit of information I do NOT want to match
This is the end of this bit

This is a random bit of information from 0 to 1.
  This is a non-random bit of information I do want to match
This is the end of this bit
```

And (attempting) the following regex:

```
/This is a random bit(?:(?!NOT).)*?This is the end/g
```

Why is this not matching?

Regexr.com link: http://regexr.com/3db8m

What I'm looking to accomplish:

1) Determine a match based on a partial string of a line

2) Determine a match that ends with a partial string of a line

3) NOT capture based on some random string inside that start/end of a match.

*edit*

The patterns suggested in the original question were entirely too complicated for my meager understanding of Regex.  Further, the suggestion of (?s) was throwing errors on regexr.com (ERROR: Invalid target for quantifier), so I reconstructed the question here.

If, indeed, there is a method to edit a question once asked, I apologize for not finding the edit link.  I did find this edit link, as this question was marked as a 'duplicate' and 'previously answered'.

Respectfully, an answer not understood is no answer.  As the author and seeker of the information contained in both this, and my previous question, I state that Maximilian Gerhardt's answer was the more correct (for me, at least).

Also, no idea if this is what was expected of this edit?  I usually resort to StackOverflow when I've left a large enough dent on my desk.  If I'm mis-using the site, again, I apologize :)

Comment: A cortect answer is already given - do not alter the patterns suggested.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Don't use `.` with text that has newlines in it..*
Working example:

http://regexr.com/3db92

[image]

Comment: That did it - now, teach a man to fish, yadda yadda - why do I not want to use the dot with newlines?

Also, say I wanted ONLY the one with NOT - how might I flip this around?

Comment: Because http://i.stack.imgur.com/rPxQp.png. In short, `.` matches everything **but** newlines, and inside your text you want to match you have several newlines. The Regex would stop matching exactly there.

Comment: I didn't realize the dot matches all BUT newlines, thank you.  If I wanted to flip this around to only get the matches WITH NOT, how might I do so?

Comment: How about rewriting it as  http://i.stack.imgur.com/kZOgL.png ? Arbitrary text which must have a "NOT" inside, and your static start and endstring.

Comment: Let me test a bit of understanding: This is a random bit = start, then a non capturing group (?:[anythingatall]NOT[anythingatall]) this is the end.  So in effect, I've got my start phrase, check everything for NOT, and the end phrase?

Comment: Exactly. In the beginning I wanted to use a positive lookahead `(?=NOT)`, but I'm confused as to why that wasn't working myself. Maybe you can get it to work without having two `[\s\S]*?` matches. (`This is a random bit[\s\S]*(?=NOT)[\s\S]*?This is the end` but that's basically the same as before.)

Comment: Thank you, sir.  I appreciate the help :)

Comment: The answer is actually not optimal for  C#. There is no point using [\s\S] in C# as it supports Dotall mode.